# Get YouTube video ID from URL with Python and Regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I would like to retrieve the video ID part of a YouTube URL which is part of a HTML anchor element like so using regex:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC2blnl0WTE">Some text</a>
```

I have looked around for some solutions. I found one from a Javascript solution which took the video ID from the url like so:

```
/https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig
```

I would like to use this in Python as it supports every variance of YouTube's URLs. I implemented it in my Python script:

```
string = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*', r'\1', string)
```

And I get no replacements. I removed the `/` and `/ig` from the regex as they are only in Javascript however I still can't get it to pick up the video ID. Once I am able to pick up the ID, I can easily change around the regex to remove the anchor element.

What have I done wrong with my solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this (scroll right to see part denoted by `^^`) is supposed to be a negative lookahead:

```
https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*
                                                                                                         ^^
```

I believe it should be a non-capturing group (i.e., `?!` should be `?:`).

```
>>> import re

>>> html = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC2blnl0WTE">Some text</a>'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"""https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?:[?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*""", re.IGNORECASE)
>>> re.search(pattern,  html).groups()
('NC2blnl0WTE',)
```

**EDIT:** Notice that I also had to use `re.IGNORECASE`. This is because the regex, as-is, won't match the `www` in `www.youtube.com`. You would need `[0-9A-Z-]` to be `[0-9A-Za-z-]`. However, it is safer just ignoring the case so you don't have to worry about other text in the URL.

**EDIT2:** As a negative lookahead, it means you would never be able to have a match when the URL is followed by the ending and closing of your anchor tag (`">blah blah blah</a>`).

Answer (score 4):

I use somthing like belowe, based on [Youtube I.D parsing for new URL formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693218/youtube-i-d-parsing-for-new-url-formats), [Python regex convert youtube url to youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705996/python-regex-convert-youtube-url-to-youtube-video).

```
import re

test_links = """
    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y6HSHwhVlY',
    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?/watch?other_param&v=5Y6HSHwhVlY',
    'http://www.youtube.com/v/5Y6HSHwhVlY',
    'http://youtu.be/5Y6HSHwhVlY', 
    'http://www.youtube.com/embed/5Y6HSHwhVlY?rel=0" frameborder="0"',
    'http://m.youtube.com/v/5Y6HSHwhVlY',
    'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/5Y6HSHwhVlY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US',
    'http://www.youtube.com/',
    'http://www.youtube.com/?feature=ytca
"""

pattern = r'(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(?:com|be)\/(?:watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=|embed\/|v\/|.+\?v=)?([^&=\n%\?]{11})'

result = re.findall(pattern, test_links, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

print(result)
```

But i really dont know if I am up to date.

**edit**

allow all subdomians